# How do I pass arguments from a child function to a parent reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactstrap

I have created a simple app component which renders a side bar and a dashboard. On a link click within the sidebar, I want to do an AJAX request and change the state of the dashboard. I have moved the click handler function to the index.js app component so it can pass the props down to the dashboard.

index.js:

```
import React from "react";

import { NavBar } from "./components/NavBar";
import { NavBarSide}  from "./components/NavBarSide";
import { Dashboard} from "./components/Dashboard"

import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {

    handleNavClick(url) {
        console.log(url)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <div className="row">
                        <Dashboard/>
                        <NavBarSide clickHandler={(url) => this.handleNavClick(url)}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


render(<App/>, window.document.getElementById("root"));
```

My NavBarSide is like so...

NavBarSide.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

export  class NavBarSide extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Nav className="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul className="nav flex-column">
                        <NavItem className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.props.clickHandler("/api/highest/price")}>Highest Price</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Instead of the expected behaviour, this function appears to immediately execute.

If there is a better way of doing this (I think with react-router v4) it would be helpful if that was also included.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default class NavBarSide extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // Bind the function only once - on creation
        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.props.clickHandler("/api/highest/price");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Nav className="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
                <div className="sidebar-sticky">
                    <ul className="nav flex-column">
                        <NavItem className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink className="nav-link" href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Highest Price</NavLink>
                        </NavItem>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </Nav>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the function inside another. 
Like this:

> onClick={()=>this.props.clickHandler("/api/highest/price")}

If not the render will execute the funcion on mount because you are trigering with the "(...)"

Comment: While this works, it creates a function instance every time the component renders.

Comment: This is a common pattern when you pass functions. Another way is to pass throught bind statement but this only will work if it's a method of your class

Comment: Now, you could declare a method in your Navside  component that executes your this.props.function  and call that method with this.MyMethod.bind(this)

Comment: Being common does not make it right. It is equally common to bind(this) in the render as well...